# want to setup an Android app that will connect to a backend database

Tags: php, android, database

I want to setup an Android app that will connect to a backend database (web/database server that I maintain). What are some good resources for doing so?.my webserver is build with php

Comment: This has been asked a million times here on this site. Please do a quick search. (Btw, you'll see that RESTful is a commonly recommended approach.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would connect to your database through a WebService.

Popular choices are:

- SOAP (your webserver / PHP software must implement a SOAP protocol) - take a look here http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/ and wikipedia on SOAP
- custom JSON API - same like SOAP, but in a protocol called JSON (more concise)
- Your custom API

You might want to refrain from using any JDBC alike connections. Others have asked this https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[android]+jdbc